# Modify and reorder command line arguments in bash

Tags: bash

How you can reorder command line arguments in bash? In this case I want to simply move first arg (`$1`) to certain position and set `$1` to empty value.

Here's my attempt:

```
#!/bin/bash

FIRST=$1
$1=

echo $* $FIRST
```

Gives:

```
% ./test.sh foo bar quux
./test.sh: line 4: foo=: command not found
foo bar quux foo
```

It should output:

```
bar quux foo
```

Comment: It would be useful to understand the use case. To achieve the question as asked you can simply do `set -- '' [other parameters] "$1" [other parameters]`. If for example you are doing argument parsing, look into `getopt`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't assign to the positional parameters individually (except in zsh, where it's `1=value`, matching all other assignments).

If you want to move the first argument to the last, that's simple to do with `shift`, this would output `b c a`:

```
set -- a b c
temp=$1
shift
echo "$@" "$temp"
```

Moving to the middle is a bit trickier, in Bash you could use `"${@:n:m}"` to get
the arguments before and after the insertion point. It expands the first *m* arguments starting at *n*. This gives `b c a d e f g` (moving the first to the third position):

```
set -- a b c d e f g
echo "${@:2:2}" "$temp" "${@:4}"
```

Of course you could clear `$1` with shift too here, just change the indexes accordingly.

---

Note that there's a difference between an argument that's the empty string, and one that doesn't exist. `"$@"` and `"${@:n:m}"` will keep empty elements as just that, while an (unquoted) `$*` will concatenate all the arguments, and then split them on whitespace. That would remove empty arguments, but also split ones with spaces. Compare:

```
$ set -- foo '' 'bar bar'
$ printf ":%s\n" "$@"
:foo
:
:bar bar
$ printf ":%s\n" $*
:foo
:bar            
:bar
```

(The unquoted expansion also goes through filename expansion, so `*` would expand to all files in the current directory, etc.)